# How can I get value from promise & use in another function?

Tags: reactjs, function, variables

Let me explain the issue, I am trying to show some details in a modal. I am using table in the modal to show details. In one section, I need the product name which is returned from a database query and I have to use that value returned from the database. The code for table is as follows:

```
<tbody>
                            {item.cartItems.map((item, i) =>
                                <tr key={item._id}>
                                    <th scope="row">{i + 1}</th>
                                    <th><img src={`${API}/product/photo/${item.product}`} alt={item.product.name} width="60px" height="50px" /></th>
                                    <td>{**data returned from database**}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{item.count}</td>
                                    <td align="center">৳ {item.price * item.count} </td>
                                </tr>
                            )}
                        </tbody>
```

To get the data from the database, I am using a function

```
const getProdcutName = id => {
    var productName;
    getProductDetails(id)
        .then(response => {
            productName = response.data.name;
        });
    return productName;
}
```

But I can't access the value. The main thing is, in every Iteration I need to send the **{item.product}** to **getProductName(id)** and I need the name from the database in return. But I can't access the data from promise scope to return it.

Comment: try to keep your code correctly indented, makes it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const getProdcutName = (id) => {
    return getProductDetails(id)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data.name;
        });
    }
```

and you can get the value like this:

```
await getProdcutName(...)    // must be inside async function
```

if you want to use the value in that function, then:

```
 const getProdcutName = async (id) => {
     const name = await getProductDetails(id)
         .then(response => {
             return response.data.name;
         });
    console.log(name)
 }
```

Comment: How can I call a async function inside map with the HTML table? 
{item.cartItems.map((item, i) =>
**Here**
                                <tr key={item._id}>
                                    <th scope="row">{i + 1}</th>
                                    <th><img src={`${API}/product/photo/${item.product}`} alt={item.product.name} width="60px" height="50px" /></th>
                                    <td>{**data returned from database**}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )}

Comment: You have to call it inside a specific component lifecycle, based on your needs, and store it in a state

Comment: Yes, I can do that but I need to fetch data from the database every time my item.cartItems iterates. In that case, If I had to call it inside a lifecycle, I have to send the id parameter but without iterating how can i do that? Can you please help me out briefly?
**const getProductName = async (id) => {
        await getProductDetails(id)
            .then(response => setProductName(response.data.name));
    }
    // useEffect(() => {
    //      getProductName(id);
    // }, [])**
** {item.cartItems.map((item, i) => <td>{I need to call the function here by passingthe parameter}</td>**

Comment: If you have to call a request on each iteration, separate your "tr" content in a different content, and make a request inside that component. const Tr = ({item}) => { useEffect(() => {here is the logic for fetching}, [item.id]);  return <tr>...content</tr>}